# How to configure locally hosted nginx with the tomcat application running inside docker

Tags: tomcat, docker, nginx

I know its little bit odd to ask this question but, i am unable to find any resources to do it. Can any one explain me how can achieve this. I have nginx server which is hosted on machine and also have one web application which is deployed using tomcat inside the docker container.

Now in nginix conf file

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     yourdomain.com;
  root            /etc/tomcat8/webapps/apple;

  proxy_cache one;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
```

Now what i have to provide `root` folder path? which is inside the docker container.
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Since you are proxying all traffic (location /) to another service (127.0.0.1:8080), the "root" directive is simply removable. That said, if your docker container is running and mapped on port 8080 your config should work. If you are having errors post them on the question.

Comment: What if docker pointing towards say `8070`, then what should i have to do.